# pandas groupby column with rolling mean, limited between datetimes, without iterating over each row

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have data in a dataframe as follows:

```
ROWS = 1000
df = pandas.DataFrame() 
df['DaT'] = pandas.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=ROWS, freq='H')
df['cat'] = numpy.random.choice(['a','b','c'],size=ROWS)    
df['val'] = numpy.random.randint(2,size=ROWS)
df['r10'] = df.groupby(['cat'])['val'].apply(lambda x: x.rolling(10).mean() )
```

I need to calculate a column that, is grouped by category 'cat', and is a rolling (10periods) mean of the value 'val' column, but the rolling mean for a given row cannot include values from the day it occurs on.

The desired result ('wanted') can be generated as follows:

```
df['wanted'] = numpy.nan
for idx, row in df.iterrows():    
    Rdate = row['DaT'].normalize() 
    Rcat  = row['cat']
    try:     df.loc[idx,'wanted'] = df[(df['DaT'] < Rdate) & (df['cat'] == Rcat) ]['val'].rolling(10).mean().iloc[-1]
    except:  df.loc[idx,'wanted'] = numpy.nan
```

The above is an awful solution, but gets the result. It is very slow for 100000+rows that need to go through. Is there are more elegant solution?
I have tried using combinations of shift and even quantize to get a more efficient solution, but no success yet

Comment: It looks like you only want to the last value calculated so you shouldn't need all data from each 'cat' - take the last 25 or 30 values and see if you get the same rolling mean. there's a subset that you'll have t test on but you don't need the hundreds or thousands to get a 10 period mean. that should cut your time considerably.

Comment: Last value of the rolling mean was a good idea thanks, I did then find a workaround using a temp df, groupby category and normalised datetime as, then carrying out a merge as follows:
df['DaN'] = df['DaT'].apply(lambda x: x.normalize())
temp  =    df.groupby(['cat','DaN'])['r10'].nth(-1).reset_index()
temp['wanted'] = temp.groupby('cat')['r10'].shift(1)
temp=temp.drop(['r10'],axis=1)
df = df.merge(temp, on=['cat','DaN'],how='left')

Comment: Glad it worked out.